# jQgrid Column and row header

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface, jqgrid

We can create Tables using jQgrid and bind the values to it. But can we create a table such that it should have column header and row header(Ex : attached image). So that when user scroll from top to bottom then Column header must always visible and when user scroll from left to right then Row header must always visible..

[image: Column and Row header]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQgrid provide option `frozen:true` which freeze column so try below code in your jQgrid:

```
columnModel = { "name":"columnHeader", "width":80, align:'left', "sortable":false, frozen:true }
```